# C# Null Object design pattern behavior in EntityFramework models implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entities, null-object-pattern

I'm updating the framework of a project from `asp.net core 3.1` to `.NET 6` following the documentation on `microsoft learn`.
Everything seems transparent enough, so I decided to refactor the code by enabling the `null object design pattern`.

I noticed a particular behavior in the entity models, in particular a relationship between my custom table and the users table which inherits from `IdentityUser`.

These **were** the tables:

```cs
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        UserClaims = new HashSet<IdentityUserClaim<int>>();
        UserLogins = new HashSet<IdentityUserLogin<int>>();
        UserTokens = new HashSet<IdentityUserToken<int>>();
        UserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserInRoles>();
        ActivityMandatoryUserDocument = new HashSet<ActivityMandatoryUserDocuments>();
        Subscriber = new();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<int>> UserClaims { get; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<int>> UserLogins { get; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserToken<int>> UserTokens { get; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserInRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }

    // my custom tables navigation properties
    public virtual Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActivityMandatoryUserDocuments> ActivityMandatoryUserDocument { get; set; }  
}
```

```cs
public class Subscriber : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public Subscriber()
    {
      User = new();
    }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? CF { get; set; }
    public char Sesso { get; set; }
    public string? Ente { get; set; }
    public int? CndcecLevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastRemoteUpdate { get; set; }

    public int FK_User { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; };

    public int? FK_Ordine { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FK_Ordine")]
    public virtual Ordini_ODCEC? Ordine { get; set; }

    public GuestType? GuestType { get; set; }
    public string? GuestTypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

6
For completeness I also report the `BaseEntity` class:

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity { }

public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey> : BaseEntity
    where TKey : struct
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is the mapping between the two navigation properties in my `DbContext` class:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriber>()
  .HasOne(f => f.User)
  .WithOne(d => d.Subscriber)
  .HasForeignKey<Subscriber>(d => d.FK_User);
```

Then, in the application, when I log in for example, the `UserManager` and `SignInManager` objects instantly turned off debugging without going into exception execuiting any method of them (`SingIn` or `SignInAsync` for example), not even by inserting a global exception middleware. The only thing i see before the application stops is the query executed through the `Output Window` which I could see colored red through an extension, as if there was an error.

After a few tries, I solved the problem by changing the navigation properties declaration from `new()` to `null!`:

```cs
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        // ...
        Subscriber = null!;  // was = new();
    }

    // ...
    public virtual Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriber : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public Subscriber()
    {
      User = null!; // was = new();
    }

    // ...

    public int FK_User { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; };
}
```

In this way, `Entityframework` managers no longer have any problems executing their methods.

I was wondering what `null!` actually does to this point what is the correct way to declare non-nullable navigation properties in this context.

Thanks!

Comment: [Reference navigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations#reference-navigations) - *Reference navigations must have a setter, although it does not need to be public. Reference navigations should not be automatically initialized to a non-null default value; doing so is equivalent to asserting that an entity exists when it does not.*